# try catch around entire app

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, try-catch

I was wondering if it is possible to put a try catch around the entire app?  My plan was to do this and then present any errors in a UIAlertView with an 'email developer' button that prepopulates an email to me.

Although not a perfect user experience, better than the app simply crashing.

Comment: Not really.  Just let it crash and you will at least get a stacktrace.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by entire app? You will have to put it in different places for different pieces of code.

Comment: I fear you can't since exceptions will be caught somewhere in the event loop. That is, there is no exception that will leave the `main` function.

Comment: @CharlieSeligman You would need a solution that catches exceptions in any thread. That is, the solution in this link only works when the exception is thrown on the main thread - AND if it gets passed through to the main function (which I believe is not the case, since iOS catches all exceptions earlier in the event loop. But you can test this quickly).

Comment: Ugh. Not sure what happened with my comment, so here it is again. **You should not be doing this.** If your code's crashing, find the bug and fix it instead. Don't try to circumvent crashes by hacking a huge exception handler around the top-level logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something nice.
'NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler'.

in your applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions add:

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleException);
```

And of course add the c function to this class:

```
void HandleException(NSException *exception)
{
        int32_t exceptionCount = OSAtomicIncrement32(&UncaughtExceptionCount);
if (exceptionCount > UncaughtExceptionMaximum)
{
    return;
}

NSArray *callStack = [UncaughtExceptionHandler backtrace];
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[exception userInfo]];
[userInfo
    setObject:callStack
    forKey:UncaughtExceptionHandlerAddressesKey];

[[[[UncaughtExceptionHandler alloc] init] autorelease]
    performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleException:)
    withObject:
        [NSException
            exceptionWithName:[exception name]
            reason:[exception reason]
            userInfo:userInfo]
    waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Add the handleException method to display the error whenever you want.

EDIT:
You can even see the stack trace: see 'callStackSymbols' of NSException.

Comment: And how do you (as a developer) get to see the stacktrace?

Comment: I actually don't know, but this is not what Charlie asked for. He wanted to display the error and send it. It's better than nothing...

Comment: Do you think that the main thread run loop will be running at the moment when HandleException is called? I'm not sure that performSelectorOnMainThread is going to work.

Comment: I am fixing my answer - you CAN see the stack trace - callStackSymbols property of NSException.

Comment: @AviTsadok I disagree.  I think using this solution will result in many exceptions being raised "in the wild" which you are totally unaware of, and in cases where users report them you don't have enough information to fix the bugs.

Comment: @trojanfoe But if you save yourself a log, you can send it with the mail, instead of a stack trace. Although I edited my answer by saying stack trace is available.

Comment: @AviTsadok I understand that.  In my own (mac) app I handle exceptions and send my app's log file to my web server for analysis, avoiding Apple's infrastructure.  But that solution requires much more code than shown here.  Half a solution is worse than no solution in this case.

Comment: @trojanfoe But as I said, you do have the stack trace. What else do you need? Besides, I cannot give him the full solution such as logging, he can continue easily from this point.

Comment: when app crashes we can save the crash reason in defaults and when we open app for next time we canshow in alert or send mail. I'm using this in my applications.

Comment: This is **NOT** good! 1. The stack trace will only contain symbols if you don't strip them from the binary. 2. On iOS most system symbols will not show up but show `<redacted>` instead (due to internal iOS optimizations). 3. You can not use Xcode symbolication infrastructure to symbolicate the report and see line numbers. 4. Why not using a proper crash reporting solution, e.g. something based on http://www.PLCrashReporter.org !?

Comment: Kerni - that looks good that open source link you provided. Will have a look into it. Thanks :-)